# MySQL - Looking for items that are associated with one tag but not another

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation to crack.

1. I have items that are tagged.
2. These tags belong to categories A and B.
3. I want to search for items by category A tags.
4. If the item has been tagged with tags of both categories, I will not want them.

```
    +---------+--------+--------------+
    | Item ID | Tag ID | Tag Category |
    +---------+--------+--------------+
    |       1 |      1 | A            |
    |       1 |      2 | A            |
    |       1 |      3 | B            |
    |       2 |      1 | A            |
    |       2 |      2 | A            |
    |       3 |      3 | B            |
    +---------+--------+--------------+
```

So when I run my query, I should only get back item 2.

Comment: Made a mistake, it should return item 2.  Item 2 has 2 tags and both tags belong to category A.  It has not category B tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `sub-query`.

Try this:

```
select * from t1 
where `Item ID` in 
    (select `Item ID` from t1
    group by `Item ID`
    having COUNT(DISTINCT `Tag Category`) < 2)
    and `Tag Category` = 'A';
```